# How to use ES6 modules inside jest.config.js files

Tags: javascript, babeljs, jestjs, puppeteer, babel-jest

I have a bunch of files that are configuring my Jest tests. I need them to specify environment for Puppeteer browser and setup/teardown behaviours.

```
 module.exports = {
   globalSetup: './jest-config/setup.js',
   globalTeardown: './jest-config/teardown.js',
   testEnvironment: './jest-config/puppeteerEnv.js',
   testResultsProcessor: './jest-config/testResultsProcessor.js',
 };
```

Right now i have a .babelrc file inside my repository with "env" preset and it transpiles my tests files and allows to use imports inside my code. Although jest-config files are not affected by transpilation and i can't use there preferred syntax.

```
/jest-config/teardown.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import 
TestResultManager from '../helpers/testResultsManager';
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

Is there any possibility that I can use the import syntax in jest-config files such as teardown/setup or reporters?

Thanks.

Comment: Any solution to this problem >